# Ansible-playbook: list all servers as comma separated and exclude own server

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have three servers

```
[servers]
server1 
server2 
server3
```

I would like to create for each server list of servers without including itself: for example

- for server1: it should be server2,server3;
- for server2: it should be server1,server3;
- for server3: it should be server1,server2;

I can create list of all servers but don't know how to exclude one server ?

```
- hosts: servers
  vars:
    network_check_list: "{{groups['servers']|join(',')}}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `difference` filter with a single element list containing the current targeted server as argument:

```
---
- hosts: servers
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    network_check_list: "{{ groups['servers'] | difference([inventory_hostname]) | join(',') }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: network_check_list
```

Since the jinja2 expression is interpreted on spot and for each run on a particular server, you can keep this definition in your playbook vars and it will be adapted to each context in the task. here is the result (used your example inventory):

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory play.yml

PLAY [servers] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "network_check_list": "server2,server3"
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "network_check_list": "server1,server3"
}
ok: [server3] => {
    "network_check_list": "server1,server2"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
server1                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server2                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
server3                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters